# Find Id to resize image (avoid memory leaks)

Tags: android, image, resize

My app has a button which allows the user to pick a photo from gallery and display it in a ImageView. The problem is, as you know, that the images taken from the camera are HUGE so i'd like to resize them.

I found this method which i'd like to try:

```
int inSample = 4; 

opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = inSample;

Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), imgResId, opts);
```

The problem is that i only have the URI of the image taken and i don't know how to convert it or to find its ID.

Answer (score 1):

Uris - if supported by the `ContentProvider`- can be used to open an `InputStream` which then can be used to decode the `Bitmap`.

So it should work more like this.

```
int inSample = 4;

opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = inSample;
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Uri uri = getUri(); // whatever it is

// this will need some exception handling
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cr.openInputStream(uri), opts);
```

Comment: the method OpenStream(uri) is undefined for the type Content Resolver

Comment: oops, it is [`ContentResolver#openInputStream(Uri)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream%28android.net.Uri%29)